Postgres Replication to existing active database server
I'm working on a large project that includes some postgres database work, but I'm not very familiar w/ the details of postgres.  Basically, I need to set-up a read-only DB that is a copy of our production database.  In general, this is pretty easy, and I got it working on my lab.
Now here's the issue....
Our current database server has 6 databases on it.  In order to save money, instead of building another DB server, I'd like to use an existing DB server (that currently housed R&D databases) to house the read-only replica.
In my research, it seems like this isn't possible using the native postgresql tools.
Am I missing anything?  Is there a way to do this?

You should ask on [DBA.se]
